# white lines in pyplot pdf export

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, seaborn

I'm trying to create a distplot with seaborn. Here is my code:

```
a = np.random.randn(1000)
sns.distplot(a, kde=False)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("temp.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Here is the resulting plot:

[image: image from jupyter notebook]

The saved pdf file contains white lines:

[image: white lines]

How do I remove them?

This seems to be a common problem:

[unknown white lines when saving pie chart as pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363657/unknown-white-lines-when-saving-pie-chart-as-pdf)

Maybe it's not even specific to python, but related to the underlying pdf renderer:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38598/why-are-there-unwanted-white-lines-appearing-in-a-pdf-print-proof

Comment: Add an edgecolor via `linewidth` or `edgecolor`

Comment: Or better maybe, use `plt.hist(..., histtype='stepfilled')`